# How do you get rid of a bf bifta

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I accidentally "purchased" 3 BF Biftas and want to permanently get rid of it and all the cars i want are expensive. So if i get two impounded and fill up my garage with crappy stolen cars and then sell those will it get rid of the unwanted BF Biftas? I tried to destroy them but when I tried to call my insurance they would show up and it was a big hassle. What should i do to permanently have the Bifta out of my garage?

Comment: I think you've mistagged, what game are you referring to?

Comment: @Sconibulus It's either GTA V or the Online version. 99% sure it's the online version, but it can be changed if it's not. It's better to have it have this tag than the LoL one, as it's much closer.

Answer (score 5):

In online, the only way to permanently get rid of a car is to overwrite it in your garage.  You can do this by trying to drive a car into your full garage.  You will get a prompt that your garage is full and you must choose a car to replace if you want to store the car.  This also works if you buy a car online with a full garage.

Comment: +1 and it's also worth noting that with a bit of investigation you can find some VERY good cars that spawn and you can have, that you can't buy.  The Ocelot F620, for example, I drive more than any of the supercars I bought... http://gta.wikia.com/F620

Answer (score -1):

If you reach the limit on your garage and want to buy a car, you will have to overwrite some cars, or selling them. In this case, if you buy a car and overwrite the Bf Bifta, it will automatically delete it.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this information isn't covered in the already available answer.